# Python datetime.datetime.fromisoformat and time difference

Tags: python, datetime

I am quite confident that on `November 4, 2022` time difference between New York and London was `4 hours`.

Here's the code I am trying:

```
import pytz
import datetime

str_time = '2022-11-04 12:19:31.507025-04:00'
test_obj = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(str_time)
tz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
datetime_obj = datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 4, 12, 19, 31, 0,   tz)
print(test_obj < datetime_obj)
```

It prints `True`, which I believe is incorrect.

I think this is due to time difference. Somehow it takes the time difference between New York and UTC is `5 hours`.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified below line in your code, you can give it a try -

```
datetime_obj = tz.localize(datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 4, 12, 19, 31, 0))
```